# How to show the categories filters on the left sidebar in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Ho to show the categories filter in the left sidebar in the categories pages similar to search results page?
I have enabled the left sidebar template for categories apges but it only shows the price filters.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that must be configured in order to activate an attribute in the category layered navigation (left side category filter).

First, the `Is Anchor` setting on the *Display Settings* tab must be set to `Yes` for each category that you would like to show within the layered navigation. `Is Active` must also be set to `Yes` as well to ensure the category is active.

[image: Set category Is Anchor to yes.]

[image: Set category to active.]

Second, the `Use in Layered Navigation` setting must be set to one of the filterable options (either **Filterable (with results)** or **Filterable (no results)**) for any product attribute you would like to use as a filter on the category pages.

[image: Set attribute to one of the filterable options for layered navigation.]

Once you have saved your category and attribute settings, you need to `Update Magento Indexes` (including attributes) and `Clear Magento Cache`.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this Question it may help to you .

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654430/subcategories-in-layered-navigation-filter

also you can install below extension which allow you category filter

https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html

Hope this will help you or solve your concern

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Catalog --> Manage categories`, select a category you want to check and make sure that

1. Include in Navigation Menu in General tab is set to Yes
2. Category Is Active
3. On Display tab, Is Anchor is set to Yes.

**Reorganize index Category** Flat Data and **flush cache**.